# Flutter Android application is not installing after release signing

Tags: android, flutter, apk, digital-signature, release

If I build apk with *debug* signing config - everything is ok.

If I build apk with *release* signing config, where I use these in build.grade from [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android):

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
```

my application is not installing on a real device. I have uninstalled past debug installations.

I have generated the key and added key.properties file.
I have my build successfully done, but apk is not getting installed with the corresponding popup. The message is "App not installed.".

I only tried to run `flutter build apk` command with `--split-per-abi` flag. The result is the same for every generated apk.
And also tried to build an app bundle. Same.

Comment: What is the exact `adb install` command you use for installation and what is the error message shown when installation fails. Please include both as text (not screenshot)  into your question by editing it.

Comment: @Robert I don't use `adb install` command. I run apk file on device. The exact message is: "App not installed.".